# Excel - Mark a cell with "X" if document exists based on a Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, formula

Not sure how to explain this properly, but I made a pivot table that contains a list of names and whether that person has the following documents: Estimate, Planning, and MS. On the pivot table it shows the value of the documents, if they have 1 or 2, or 0.

I made another spreadsheet that labels the 3 documents and the people. Based on the pivot table, I need a formula that will mark an X where the document exists (instead of having to manually put an X)

I hope I am explaining correctly!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood your requirements, you can do that directly in a PivotTable using a Custom Number Format, which looks like this:

[image]

You get to the Custom Number Format dialog this way:

[image]

...and once there, add a Custom Number Format of x;;;

[image]